# Pod creation in EKS cluster fails with FailedScheduling error

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

I have created a new EKS cluster with 1 worker node in a public subnet. I am able to query node, connect to the cluster, and run pod creation command, however, when I am trying to create a pod it fails with the below error got by describing the pod. Please guide.

```
    Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
    Events:
      Type     Reason            Age   From               Message
      ----     ------            ----  ----               -------
      Warning  FailedScheduling  81s   default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 Too many pods. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
  Warning  FailedScheduling  16m                 default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 2 Too many pods, 2 node(s) had untolerated taint {node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable: }, 2 node(s) were unschedulable. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
  Warning  FailedScheduling  16m                 default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 2 node(s) had untolerated taint {node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable: }, 2 node(s) were unschedulable, 3 Too many pods. preemption: 0/3 nodes are available: 1 No preemption victims found for incoming pod, 2 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
  Warning  FailedScheduling  14m (x3 over 22m)   default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had untolerated taint {node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable: }, 1 node(s) were unschedulable, 2 Too many pods. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 1 No preemption victims found for incoming pod, 1 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
  Warning  FailedScheduling  12m                 default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 1 Too many pods, 2 node(s) had untolerated taint {node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable: }, 2 node(s) were unschedulable. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
  Warning  FailedScheduling  7m14s               default-scheduler  no nodes available to schedule pods
  Warning  FailedScheduling  105s (x5 over 35m)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 Too many pods. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
```

I am able to get status of the node and it looks ready:

```
kubectl get nodes  
NAME                         STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
ip-10-0-12-61.ec2.internal   Ready    <none>   15m   v1.24.7-eks-fb459a0
```

While troubleshooting I tried below options:

1. recreate the complete demo cluster - still the same error
2. try recreating pods with different images - still the same error
3. trying to increase to instance type to t3.micro - still the same error
4. reviewed security groups and other parameters in a cluster - Couldnt come to RCA

Answer (score 11, accepted):

it's due to the node's POD limit or **IP** limit on Nodes.

So if we see [official Amazon doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#AvailableIpPerENI), **t3.micro** maximum 2 interface you can use and **2** private IP. Roughly you might be getting around **4** IPs to use and **1st** IP get used by Node etc, There will be also default system PODs running as Daemon set and so.

Add new instance or upgrade to larger instance who can handle more pods.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, I tried the solution of upgrading to 't3.micro' and it didn't work. Also, may I know how the 'number of interfaces' help here to kick off the pod on a machine

Comment: did you check the document nano micro other have same interface count tried with t3.small or little more?

Comment: yes verified, let me try using t2.small has three interfaces, to see if it helps to solve the problem.

Comment: This has helped, may I know how the interfaces are going to impact the pod creation and allocation, rather, how the instances interfaces are going to get utilized?

Comment: this one might be helpful " https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/eks/latest/userguide/cni-increase-ip-addresses.html